# Can't find variable: tab in React Native's react-native-material-bottom-navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have got react-native-material-bottom-navigation library for my project (which is blank by the way). I have used exactly the same code as in the example at https://github.com/timomeh/react-native-material-bottom-navigation , line by line, but I get the following error :

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: tab

 This error is located at:
   in FullTab (at App.js:53)
   in TouchableWithoutFeedback (at TabList.js:165)
   in RCTView (at View.js:43)
   in TabList (at BottomNavigation.js:134)
   in PressFeedback (at BottomNavigation.js:132)
   in BackgroundDecorator (at BottomNavigation.js:130)
   in RCTView (at View.js:43)
   ...
```

The code from line 53 is

```
 <FullTab
  isActive={isActive}
  key={tab.key}
  label={tab.label}
  renderIcon={this.renderIcon(tab.icon)}
/>
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: That code is also surrounded by `renderTab = ({ tab, isActive }) => ( ... )` in the documentation. Are you sure you have all the relevant code?

Comment: Yes, I have all the correct imports and everything is in the class `App extends Component<Props>`

Comment: Alright. Could you include your entire component in the question? It's hard to say what might be wrong from the current code.